# "If the aggregate supply is linear, demand shocks cannot affect average unemployment", what does it mean?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

Aggregate Supply: $\pi_t =\pi_{t-1} -\alpha(u_t -\bar{u})+e_t^S$
Welfare: $W_t =-cu_t -f(\pi_t ), c>0, f''(\cdot)>0$
$\bar{u}$: natural unemployment rate
$e_t^S$: supply shock

In Romer's textbook, it says
"The linearity of aggregate supply implies that if policymakers allow demand shocks to cause fluctuations in unemployment($u_t$) and inflation($\pi_t$), average unemployment is unaffected."
and
"The linearity of social welfare implies that fluctuations in unemployment do not affect welfare".

I can't follow that sentences.
I need some mathematical calculation to prove that sentences or they are just intuitive?
Can anyone explain the economic meaning of them?

Comment: Hi: I'm just checking but did you happen to mean supply shock instead of demand shock ? I ask because I don't see a demand shock in the system. Maybe it's best to ask Romer because no one on this list answered. Just a suggestion.